# having dates as column name while executing select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to display dates as column names while executing select statement, like

```
select number as sysdate from employee;
```

But this is not working. How can i do this

Comment: Column names are "constant" in a SQL statement.  To do what you want, you would need to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: If you want to capture the information on when that data was retrieved, I typically just add another column to the query: `select sysdate as "As of", e.* from employee e`

Comment: No i am having some data in some table and i want to display like these many rcords i get on this particular date. Example 
1-3-2017(30) 1-2-2017(20) 1-1-2017(10)

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: i think using pivot or decode you can. oracle 11g use pivot and prior used decode.

Comment: To begin with, you are using a reserved word (`sysdate`) as an alias. It is like using `function`, and is something you should not do. Second, your request is not clear: You want to use data retrieved in the select statement to NAME the columns of the result?

Answer (score 0):

SQL queries work on fixed columns, i.e. the result columns (and their names) are known before executing the query.

Of course you can work with column names like "today" and the like:

```
select
  sum(case when mydate = sysdate then value end) as sum_today,
  sum(case when mydate = sysdate - 1 then value end) as sum_yesterday
from mytable;
```

but SQL cannot change the column names.

Anyway, users usually don't work with some geek SQL IDE, but with a program or website written by us. So why bother? Have SQL get you the data and then care about the layout (often with a loop and a grid) in your app.

Simply

```
select mydate, sum(value) as sum_value
from mytable
group by mydate
order by mydate;
```

and do the rest in your app.